# Option to restart a service from django admin page

Tags: django, apache, apache2, mosquitto

I am using Apache2, Django, Mosquitto. I would like to have an option in my Django admin page to restart Mosquitto MQTT server. I came across the `subprocess` module but I have no idea how to implement the above-mentioned functionality. Basically, my need is to restart Mosquitto by performing the command `sudo service mosquitto restart` because sometimes Mosquitto freeze up and restarting it is a temporary fix for this issue. Unfortunately, When this happens, I may not have access to my workstation. So it will be convenient if my Django admin page had an option to restart the Mosquitto.

I have added an admin action which is supposed to trigger restart command

```
def restart_server(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call('./reload.sh', shell=True, cwd='/home/ubuntu')


class HomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'alert_mode', 'system_version')
    actions = [restart_server,]
```

**reload.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service mosquitto restart
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: First I thought of extending Django template and adding a custom restart button and writing a view for the button click which will trigger service restart via `subprocess.call()` method. But for the time being, I choose to add an admin action in one of model admin. But I couldn't make `subprocess` work to call the restart the command